# Calculating expression with multiple fork() children?

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, system-calls

Suppose we have expression `g=(a+b)*(c+d)-(e/f)` with hard-coded arbitrary numbers for variables. I would like to calculate this expression using multiple child processes in order to better understand how fork() works.

My first attempt was to calculate `(a + b)` on child **pid1**, `(c + d)` on child **pid2**, `(e / f)` on child **pid3**, and then do summation & subtraction in the **parent** process.

Well, to my disappointment, `(a + b)` calculation done in the child process **pid1** did not affect `double expression1` variable in the parent process. I think the reason behind that - each **fork()** creates a separate memory space; as soon as a child process exits, all calculations done in that child process are gone.

What do you usually do in a situation like this? I thought maybe I could nest fork() child process within a child process to calculate `(a + b)` first; **wait**; then `(c + d)`; **wait**; `(e / f)`; **wait**; **the first child** calculates the entire expression; child **return(0)**; **parent** terminates.

But I think there's an easier solution to this problem, am I right?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of IPC — Inter-Process Communication.  Your analysis that each process has a separate address space is correct.  You will have to decide how to get each sub-process to communicate with the relevant others.  You could use shared memory, pipes, or a variety of other techniques.

Comment: The usual technique for this sort of parallelism is multi-*threading*, not multi-processing. All threads share the same address space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on using `fork()` , so here is my answer now using child process and shared memory

Note that `exit()` is used here the way it is expected by the system: to signalize if the child has exited normally or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


struct shared{
    int a_b;
    int c_d;
    int e_f;
};
const int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=6,f=2;
const key_t key = 1234;
pid_t pab,pcd,pef;
void* shared_mem;

int main(){
    //Parent process create the shared memory 
    int shmid = shmget(key,sizeof(struct shared), 0666|IPC_CREAT);
    if(shmid == -1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    //Fork child
    pab = fork();
    if(pab == 0){  
        //Inside process ab
        //attach to shared memory
        shared_mem = shmat(shmid,(void*) 0,0);
        if(shared_mem == (void*) -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        struct shared* shared_data = (struct shared*) shared_mem;
        shared_data->a_b = a +b;

        //detach
        if(shmdt(shared_mem) == -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }else {
        pcd = fork();
        if(pcd == 0){
            //Inside process cd
            //attach to shared memory
            shared_mem = shmat(shmid,(void*) 0,0);
            if(shared_mem == (void*) -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            struct shared* shared_data = (struct shared*) shared_mem;
            shared_data->c_d = c+d;

            //detach
            if(shmdt(shared_mem) == -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        }else{
            pef = fork();
            if(pef == 0){
                //Inside process ef
                //attach to shared memory
                shared_mem = shmat(shmid,(void*) 0,0);
                if(shared_mem == (void*) -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                struct shared* shared_data = (struct shared*) shared_mem;
                shared_data->e_f = e/f;

                //detach
                if(shmdt(shared_mem) == -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
        }
    }

    //Wait child process termination
    int status_ab,status_cd,status_ef;
    waitpid(pab,&status_ab,0);
    waitpid(pcd,&status_cd,0);
    waitpid(pef,&status_ef,0);

    //Check if all child exited  normally
    if(!WIFEXITED(status_ab) || !WIFEXITED(status_cd)||!WIFEXITED(status_ef)){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Parent attaches to memory 
    shared_mem = shmat(shmid,(void*) 0,0);
    if(shared_mem == (void*) -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    struct shared* shared_data = (struct shared*) shared_mem;

    //Calculate result
    int result = (shared_data->a_b)*(shared_data->c_d)-(shared_data->e_f);
    printf("Result is %d\n", result);

    //Parent detaches from shared memory and deletes
    if(shmdt(shared_mem) == -1) exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    if(shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,0) == -1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

fork()ing the processes, then waitpid()ing on their return values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    //whatever values you like:
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    int e = 15;
    int f = 6;

    int a_plus_b_pid;
    int c_plus_d_pid;
    int e_div_f_pid;

    int a_plus_b;
    int c_plus_d;
    int e_div_f;

    a_plus_b_pid = fork();
    if(a_plus_b_pid)
    {
        c_plus_d_pid = fork();
        if(c_plus_d_pid)
        {
            e_div_f_pid = fork();
            if (e_div_f_pid)
            {
                //wait for our processes to exit, with our results, and stash the computed values.
                waitpid(a_plus_b_pid, &a_plus_b, 0);
                waitpid(c_plus_d_pid, &c_plus_d, 0);
                waitpid(e_div_f_pid, &e_div_f, 0);

                //The 8 least-significant bits carry info that we're not interested in here, so shift them out:
                a_plus_b >>= 8;
                c_plus_d >>= 8;
                e_div_f >>= 8;

                printf("%d %d %d %d\n", a_plus_b, c_plus_d, e_div_f, a_plus_b * c_plus_d - e_div_f);
            }
            else
            {
                exit (e/f);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            exit (c+d);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        exit (a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to use something in a different way that it was designed for. If you call `exit()` with a  number different of zero, you are signalizing to the OS that your program failed. On the other hand, you won't be able to tell that the value returned by the child is the result of the subexpression or an error code. If you need to do IPC, use a real IPC mechanism.

Comment: I would suggest to use `popen` in that case. It gives a simple IPC enough for your needs.

Comment: The interpretation of exit is not defined.  The OS does not impose any meaning upon its value - it is simply by convention that 0 is a normal exit (since it is assumed that there is only one good way to finish) and anything else is abnormal (since there are any number of ways to fail.)  Regardless, it it hardly applicable here, since the OP was explicit that the question was academic.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version using pthreads:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>


volatile int a_b;
volatile int c_d;
volatile int e_f;
const int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=6,f=2;

void* calc_ab(void*);
void* calc_cd(void*);
void* calc_ef(void*);

int main(){
        pthread_t ab_thread, cd_thread, ef_thread;

        pthread_create(&ab_thread,NULL,calc_ab,NULL);
        pthread_create(&cd_thread,NULL,calc_cd,NULL);
        pthread_create(&ef_thread,NULL,calc_ef,NULL);
        pthread_join(ab_thread, NULL);
        pthread_join(cd_thread, NULL);
        pthread_join(ef_thread,NULL);
        int result = a_b*c_d-e_f;
        printf("Result is %d\n", result);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void* calc_ab(void* arg){ a_b = a+b;pthread_exit(NULL);}
void* calc_cd(void* arg){ c_d = c+d;pthread_exit(NULL);}
void* calc_ef(void* arg){ e_f = e/f;pthread_exit(NULL);}
```

To compile you have to link against pthread:
`gcc  pthread.c -lpthread -o teste`

**Notes**

- Note that variables that are shared between the main thread and a child thread are declared `volatile`. This prevent the compiler of doing some memory optimizations that could prevent a write done in one thread  not to be seen by others.
- Each child thread writes to a different shared variable. I wanted to keep the code simple, not having to handle synchronization explicitly.
- The main thread only reads the shared variable only after it has returned from a `pthread_join` for the thread that changed it. Again I wanted to keep the code simple, not having to handle synchronization explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need processes at all to do arbitrary computation. Emabedding an interpreter like e.g. [lua](http://www.lua.org/) might be simpler.

Of course, each process has its own address space. Type `cat /proc/self/maps` to get information about the process running that `cat` command.

If you insist on using processes to learn how they can communicate thru pipes, you might use something like [popen(3)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_popen.htm) which will use some syscalls to start and pipe a command.

```
char cmd[80];
int a, b, sum;
/// fill a & b
snprintf (cmd, sizeof(cmd), "echo $[%d + %d]", a, b);
FILE* pcmd = popen(cmd, "r");
if (fscanf (pcmd, "%d", &sum)>0) {
    // do something with sum
};
pclose(pcmd);
```

And you should read a good book like [Advanced Unix Programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). The real thing is to understand [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) like [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [dup(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup.2.html), etc.... To understand what [syscalls(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are done by some command or program, use `strace`